# Minio UI disable public listing of all bucket which has readonly policy

Tags: minio

In Minio I have a bucket that has a read-only policy, but I do not want to be viewed in Minio Browser without authentication.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

First reset recursively (optional) existing policy on  bucket

```
mc policy --recursive set none  gm/data/ibb
```

After that you can change the policy as you like

Comment: Is the original question asking to keep the read-only policy?